# PhotonView.Get(this) returns null

Tags: windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, photon

I integrate PUN 1.22 to my Unity3d wp8 project. It builds correct, but
PhotonView.Get(this) returns null. What can it be?

```
public static PhotonView Get(Component component)
{
    return component.GetComponent<PhotonView>() as PhotonView;
}

public static PhotonView Get(GameObject gameObj)
{
    return gameObj.GetComponent<PhotonView>() as PhotonView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just forget to attach PhotonView to my GameObject

The Solution:

```
this.gameObject.AddComponent<PhotonView>();
photonView = PhotonView.Get(this);
```